# How declare v-model for custom component in vue render function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have code below:

```js
...
var label_key_map = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4" }
render: (h) => {
  var form_data = {}
  for (let key in label_key_map) {
    var form_item = h(
      'FormItem',
      {props: {prop: key}},
      [h('Input', {props: {type: "text", vModel: "form_data.key"}})]
    )
  }
```

In the for-loop I want to bind the `form_data.a`, `form_data.b`, `form_data.c` to every `Input`.

But when I use  `vModel: "form_data[key]"` or `vModel: "form_data.key"`, neither work. It seems the correct way to write in general is: `vModel: "form_data.a"`?

How to solve this in the `for`-loop?

---

Edit: The actual case is an [IView `Form`](https://www.iviewui.com/components/form). Example:

```
<Form :model="formValidate">
    <FormItem label="E-mail" prop="mail">
        <Input v-model="formValidate.mail" placeholder="Enter your e-mail"></Input>
    </FormItem>
</Form>
```

My `form_data` in this example is the `formValidate`. I use the `for`-loop generate the `form_data`, but I can not use `"form_data.a"`. How to bind the `v-model` (of the custom component `Input`) now?

Comment: so what is your desire output?

Comment: @PankajBisht not output. in render function its standard code just like: vModel: ’form_data.a’but i use the for loop generate the form_data. i can^t know the key.

Comment: Why do you assign `undefined` instead of `label_key_map[key]`?

Comment: the form_data bind to the form. the form_item bind the form_data.x. the initial data should be undefined or ‘’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use arrow functions in the `render` declaration. About the usage of render functions, to generate attributes, use `attrs`, not `props`. Also, quoting the [Render Functions & JSX docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#v-model):

> There is **no direct `v-model` counterpart** in render functions - you will have to implement the logic **yourself**.

Below demos of how that could be achieved.

## Declaring, in render function, `v-model` for DOM native elements (e.g. `<input>`)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      form_data: { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4" }
  },
  render(h) { // dont use arrow function
    var self = this
    var form_items = [];
    for (let key in self.form_data) {
        var form_item = h('div', {},
            [
               key + ':',
               h('input', {
                  attrs: {type: "text"},
                  // simulate "v-model"
                  domProps: {value: self.form_data[key]}, on: {input: function (event) { self.form_data[key] = event.target.value }}
               })
            ]
        );
        form_items.push(form_item);
    }
    var form = h('form', {}, form_items);

    return h('div', {}, [
        form,
        h('pre', JSON.stringify(this.form_data)) // added for visual debug
    ]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

## Declaring, in render function, `v-model` for DOM custom components (e.g. `<Inputx>`)

In this example, the declarations simulate the usage of [IView's `<Form>`, `<FormItem>` and `<Input>`](https://www.iviewui.com/components/form), which are vue custom components. In the code below I added an `x` to the component's names so the reader at a glance don't confuse them with the native `<form>` or `<input>` (what actually happened to me at first).

```js
// declaring some custom components to simulate https://www.iviewui.com/components/form
Vue.component('Formx', {template: '<div>Form\'s model: {{ model }} <hr><slot></slot></div>', props:['model']})
Vue.component('FormItemx', {template: '<div><slot></slot></div>'})
Vue.component('Inputx', {template: '<div><input :value="value" @input="$emit(\'input\', $event.target.value)"></div>', props:['value']})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        form_data: { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4" }
    },
    render(h) { // don't use arrow function here
        var self = this
        var form_items = [];
        for (let key in self.form_data) {
            var form_item = h('FormItemx', {
                attrs: {prop: key}},
                [h('Inputx', {
                    attrs: {type: "text"},
                    // custom component "v-model"
                    model:{
                      value: self.form_data[key],
                      callback: (v) => self.$set(self.form_data, key, v),
                      expression:"form_data["+key+"]"
                    }
                })]
            );
            form_items.push(form_item);
        }
        return h('Formx', {attrs:{"model":this.form_data}}, form_items);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: i follow the iview form. the form_item has those props.

Comment: It has attributes, not props. In `<FormItem prop="user">` we have an attribute called `prop`. But, anyway, the code above was an example. If you find out it doesn't work due to attrs, then change to props.

Comment: thanks for your attention, I did not work out, and I am also looking for a solution in my way.

Comment: That's the `Form` is a iView component that bind the :model="form_data", and its <FormItem>'s <Input> bind the `form_data. property`, which is the API of iView <Form> and <Input>. I can not bind this in the generated form_data.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand what you needed, now. Can you check the updated answer? I think it should work. (If you need to see exactly what I changed, check the [revision page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49634849/revisions) of the answer.)

Comment: Great! Also, as you can see, I did some edits. But, don't worry, nothing changed, really. I added some more code example just so the answer is more helpful to the future readers, OK?  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```js
h('custom-component',{
    model:{
        value: self.form_data[key],
        callback: (v) => self.$set(self.form_data, key, v),
        expression:"form_data["+key+"]"
    }
});
```

This way can make `v-model` working, but not the recommended way of use.

My suggestion is still using `value` dom attribute and `input` event for custom component like below:

```js
h('custom-component',{
    attrs:{
        value: this.myValue
    },
    on:{
        input: val => this.myValue = val
    }
})
```

For native element：

```js
h('input',{
    attrs:{
        type:'text'
    },
    domProps:{
        value: this.myValue
    },
    on:{
        input: val => this.myValue = val
    }
})
```

More detail in code: [github.com/TerryZ/vue-plugins](https://github.com/TerryZ/vue-plugins/blob/d3008b48c3b3df2014c3af035edb6d577f3ddd43/src/components/v-region/components/SelectGroup.js#L51)